# DB2: How to set encoding for db2clp under Windows?

Tags: windows, encoding, db2

I have a DB2 that was created with encoding set to UTF-8

```
db2 create database mydb using codeset UTF-8
```

My data insert scripts are also stored in encoding UTF-8.
The problem now is that the command line processor seems to work with a different encoding as the Windows installation doesn't use UTF-8:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>chcp
Active code page: 850
```

This leads to the problem that my data (which contains special characters) is not stored correctly to the database.

Under Linux/AIX I could change the command line encoding by setting

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

How do I achieve this under Windows? I already tried

```
chcp 65001
```

**UPDATE**:
But that won't have any effect? It seems like the db2clp can't deal with the UTF-8 encoded file because it will print out junk:

```
D:\Program Files\ibm_db2\SQLLIB\BIN>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

D:\Program Files\ibm_db2\SQLLIB\BIN>type d:\tmp\encoding.sql
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, TXT) VALUES (99, 'äöü');


D:\Program Files\ibm_db2\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 connect to mydb

Datenbankverbindungsinformationen

Datenbank-Server                                                = DB2/NT64 9.5.0
SQL-Berechtigungs-ID                                            = MYUSER
Aliasname der lokalen Datenbank                                 = MYDB

D:\Program Files\ibm_db2\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 -tvf d:\tmp\encoding.sql
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, TXT) VALUES (99, 'Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼')
DB20000I  Der Befehl SQL wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

Comment: it looks like, the first character (the one before DELETE) of encloding.sql is malformed?

Comment: Yes, it looks that way. But I already removed my file, created it from scratch, removed every content in the file but still the db2 cmd line tool cannot deal with the UTF-8 encoded file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set both:

```
CHCP 65001
SET DB2CODEPAGE=1208
```

on the `db2cmd` command line, before running `db2 -tvf`. This works for databases that have `CODESET` set to `UTF-8`. To check the `CODESET` setup for database run:

```
db2 get db cfg for <your database>
```

and look for "Database code page" and "Database code set" they should be `1208` and `UTF-8` respectively.

Comment: unfortunately even this (and setting the LANG variable to en_US.UTF-8) didn't work. Any more ideas what to try? IBM documentation is giving no hints at all.

Answer (score 1):

when dealing with encodings, you have to take a careful look into your envirnoments, and where you are currently. So in your case:

- the Server stores its data in encoding A (like UTF-8)
- the client resides in an environment which has encoding B (like windows-1252)

in your client, you have to have to use the encoding of your client (or tell the client you intentionally use another encoding **on client side** (like UTF-8-encoded file inside a windows-1251 environment)!). The connection between the Client and the server is doing the work for you to change encoding B into encoding A for storing the data into the database.

Comment: As I wrote above. All the database stuff is UTF-8. It is only the Windows cmd/installation at the customer's which is not UTF-8. So I cannot change the Windows installation, but I still need to be able to load my UTF-8 data correctly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me by setting db2codepage, thanks to Mr. Zoran Regvart.
by the way, after setting, you need to execute "db2 terminate" to reset client, and then reconnect.